# how to call javascript method without onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tem.parstools.com/zeos/js/animatedcollapse.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
animatedcollapse.addDiv('bannertop', 'fade=0,speed=200,persist=1')

animatedcollapse.ontoggle=function($, divobj, state){
if (divobj.id=="bannertop") //only react to these two collapsible DIVs
document.getElementById(divobj.id+"-toggle").src=(state=="block")? "image1.png" : "image2.png"
}

animatedcollapse.init()
</script>
```

This function is called when user click on the specific image like:

```
<a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.toggle('bannertop')"><img id="bannertop-toggle" src="image_source" /></a>
```

But, I want first time my site loading this function calling automatically.

sorry for my weak English typing.
Can any body can help me?
thanks

Comment: I think this will help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the method in the script

```
animatedcollapse.toggle('bannertop')
```

inside the `<script>` tag. You might want to put this code at the bottom of the html file, right before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: thanks   its working
but with this code first time my function called

but when i click on my image no event calling now
what is my wrong?